# jquery document direction

Tags: jquery, css

I have  block in head section that contains following:

```
*, body { direction:rtl; }
```

I noticed that dir variable of jQuery is set to ltr:

```
$(function(){
   alert(this.dir); });
```

Is there a way to retrieve a concrete page direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
$('body').css('direction')
```

read more about [jQuery css](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

Answer (score 1):

In your CSS, you are using `direction` but in jQuery code you are fetching it via `dir`. You need to use `dir` in your CSS too to get correct value.

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
alert($('body').attr('dir'));
```

Good Luck!

Comment: This gets the `dir` attribute if it's been set in the HTML, but you're probably insterested in the `direction` property, which might have been inherited from `<html dir="rtl">` for instance.